# How do I sync the files in SVN development repo and my live code?

Tags: svn, synchronization

How do I sync all the code in the SVN repository (for development purposes) with the live code I have running in /home/site/public_html/, as in overwrite whatever is in live with the new code from the SVN repo (assume the SVN repo location is in /usr/bin/svn/project, just for the sake of the argument, even though it's probably far from that)?

Comment: Are you talking about updating?  Or do you mean to overwrite your changes?  You can revert, then update, or you can delete your working copy and checkout.  Of course deleting public_html with rm -rf may screw up permissions (as I have found out on occasion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do an `svn checkout` or `svn export` in /home/site/public_html.

Personally I have a checked out copy on my web server, and the repository is on the same machine. I then have a hook so that on a commit, I perform an `svn update` in the live directory, so that committing to the repository immediately makes the change live.

Comment: And don't forget to add the appropriate .htaccess (or equivalent) rules to prevent people from navigating into the .svn folder.

Comment: What type of a rule would that be (that I can add to my existing .htaccess files) - do you have an example?